# Poll application with indefinite options, prevent voting from off the options displayed

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a django voting system where you get displayed a small random amount of options from a pool of candidates, and the way i submit the votes is by using the ID's of the options, but i can't think of a way to keep people from just changing the source code and submitting votes on the same option over and over, the options get displayed on the view and template like this:

> return render(request, '/vote.html', {'p': po, 'opts':
>   opts.order_by('?')[:3]

```
    {%for v in opts%}
<div class='votebox' name='{{v.id}}' onclick='vote()'></div>
{%endfor%}
```

What's a code efficient way to check if the user voted on an option that was displayed to them?

the voting option model is this

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sub_date = models.DateField()
    poll = models.ForeignKey('Poll', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='MEDIA_ROOT')
    repcount = models.IntegerField()
```

the Poll model is:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date=models.DateField()
```

and the view where it goes is this

```
def poll(request, id):
    if request.method == "GET":
        po = poll.objects.get(id=id)
        daysleft = poll.end_date - datetime.date.today()
        opts = po.submission_set.all()
        return render(request, '/vote.html', {'p': po, 'opts' : opts, 'daysl':daysleft}


    elif request.method == "POST":
        voted = request.POST.get('voteval', False)
        sub = Submission.objects.get(id=voted)
        sub.vote_count += 1
        sub.save()
```

Comment: Share the models and views related to your poll, so you can get a better answer. Also, do you want to limit users to vote just once or to vote once per candidate?

Comment: no, they can vote as many times as the want, i'll ad the model in just a sec

Answer (score 0):

I would add an intermediary model between `User` and `Submission`

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('user', 'submission'),
        )
```

Now when handling the `POST` part of the view, you can check if the user has voted on this submission before and create a new `Vote` object if he hasn't

```
elif request.method == "POST":
        voted = request.POST.get('voteval', False)
        sub = Submission.objects.get(id=voted)
        user = request.user
        try:
            vote = Vote.objects.get(user=user, submission=sub)
            # warn user that he's voted for this submission
        except Vote.DoesNotExist:
            vote = Vote.objects.create(user=user, submission=sub)
            sub.vote_count += 1
            sub.save()
```

Comment: actually logging in is not required for voting ):

Comment: @YoungVenus if you are not dealing with logged-in users you can identify them by their session key, but this is obviously not fool-proof.

Comment: I've devided to use the evercookie library, and i think it's as good as i can make it